# Xslt Concatenate two nodelists with seperator

Tags: string, xslt, concatenation, nodes, element

I am trying to concatenate two list of nodes which have child elements with a string-join but I am loosing the xml tags in the child elements

Input: 
node1:  `hello I am trying <abc> some </abc> xslt code`

node2: `but not working`

expected output

`hello I am trying <abc> some </abc> xslt code, but not working`

Comment: Assume that there are xml tags surrounding for one of the words in node 1 or node 2. I added them but some how not seen

Comment: Can you show us your input XML and your current XSLT that creates/has those two "list" of nodes? Can you explain whether you are looking for an intermediary result in the XSLT code or a final transformation result?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sequence of two element nodes containing the content you have shown and you want to create an output with a separator `,` between those nodes then one way would be to push the elements through a template that adds the separator:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:param name="seq1" select="node1, node2"/>
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$seq1"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node1 | node2">
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPJ8LVh

If you want to work on a string level with `string-join` then you first need to serialize the contents e.g.

```
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:param name="seq1" select="node1, node2"/>
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="$seq1 ! serialize(node())" separator=", "/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPJ8LVh/1

```
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:param name="seq1" select="node1, node2"/>
      <xsl:variable name="str1" select="string-join($seq1 ! serialize(node()), ', ')"/>
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="$str1"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPJ8LVh/2

As you can see, the last two examples create strings output as text, it seems more likely that you want to create a result nodes, like done in the first suggestion.